# Retrieve the path of the current source file with fish

Tags: fish

In a fish shell script, is it possible to obtain the path where the shell script lives? In bash, you can use the BASH_SOURCE variable to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to use the [status](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#status) command.

eg.

```
~/tmp> echo status -f > show_filename.fish
~/tmp> fish show_filename.fish
/home/foo/tmp/show_filename.fish
```

--

Ah, sorry - judging by your comment, I misread the question. I thought you meant the fully qualified path, instead of the script's directory.

You could just send the status result to dirname. It's not a built-in function of fish, like status is, but fish tends to outsource as much of this functionality as it can anyway (see "The law of minimalism", over in the fish [design doc](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html)). I can't see anything better commands in the docs for this, so maybe this is as good as we can get for now?

Amending the example, change the contents of show_filename.fish to be:

```
dirname (status -f)
```

Now you should get:

```
~/tmp> fish show_filename.fish
/home/foo/tmp
```

Comment: This is pretty close. Is there a pure fish way of parsing the /home/foo/tmp/show_filename.fish string to get /home/foo/tmp?

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I wanted.

Comment: `cd (dirname (status -f)); and pwd` gives the absolute path regardless whether your running the script in the current directory.